# Quiver - Object Set too large to perform search around

Tags: palantir-foundry

When trying to access a linked object I receive the message `Object Set too large to perform search around`. The reason is because my Object Set is larger than 100.000 elements.
Is it possible group data out of objects so I can reduce the np. of elements (not filtering but e.g group daily data to month level)

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is a bit old, but answering for posterity.

Since you are hitting the backend limitation for Object search around, one option is to create a subset of the data, but grouping using Authoring/Code Repositories in pyspark for example. You can then sync a separate object for the grouped data (put grouped in the name) and do search arounds using that.  You can get the month out of a date using the pyspark and then do a groupby (please ask a specific question if you face issues).

Another option is you can precompute the search arounds using a join table.  If you have a many:many relationship between the objects, you can create a join table with the primary key of the left and the right tables backing the objects using pyspark, and add the join relation in the ontology manager.

Finally, there is a second version of the Objects Store which doesn't have these restrictions but it has not be rolled out across the Foundry fleet yet.